# View triggers history in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle8

I want to have multiple triggers created on a database Oracle 8.
Can I view a trigger history, meaning modifications, even though I don't have a DDL trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You should have a version control system though, where you each revision of your script will be stored. You do have a version control system don't you? If you don't, get one; as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a software we wrote called DB History.
If all you want is to view schema history (ddl trigger is part of the schema) the free version is enough to solve your problem.
https://www.seracode.com/Oracle

Answer (score -1):

Try the following data dictionary.

```
DESC user_triggers;
```